# Duplicate entry happens in hibernate while I am trying to call saveorupdate() method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My application contains several threads running concurrently and all threads either inserts or updates several rows in my tables, So I am using saveOrUpdate() to avoid duplicate entry issue. But it happens several times.

My Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (`id` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL COMMENT 'It will be the post_id in )
```

My HBM

```
<class name="com.xminds.bestfriend.frontend.model.Question" table="question" >
    <id name="id" type="string">
        <column name="id" length="100" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="users" class="com.xminds.bestfriend.frontend.model.Users" fetch="select">
        <column name="answer_uid" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="questionType" class="com.xminds.bestfriend.frontend.model.QuestionType" fetch="select">

        <column name="question_type_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="data1" type="string">
        <column name="data1" length="65535" />
    </property>
    <property name="data2" type="string">
        <column name="data2" length="65535" />
    </property>
    <property name="fbCreatedDate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="fb_created_date" length="19" />
    </property>
    <property name="permaLink" type="string">
        <column name="perma_link" length="1000" />
    </property>
    <property name="fbUpdatedDate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="fb_updated_date" length="19" />
    </property>
    <property name="contentActivity" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="content_activity" />
    </property>
    <property name="nbConsumptions" type="int">
        <column name="nb_consumptions" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="createdDate" type="date">
        <column name="created_date" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="updatedDate" type="date">
        <column name="updated_date" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="cover_url" type="string">
      <column name="cover_url" length="1000"/>
    </property>

    <property name="category" type="string">
      <column name="category" length="1000"/>
    </property>
    <property name="width" type="int">
        <column name="width" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="height" type="int">
        <column name="height" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="coverOffsetX" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="cover_offset_x" />
    </property>
    <property name="coverOffsetY" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="cover_offset_y" />
    </property>
    <property name="latitude" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="latitude" precision="12" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="longitude" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="longitude" precision="12" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="is_active" type="boolean">
        <column name="is_active" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="questionConsumptions" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="question_id" length="100" not-null="true">
                <comment>QuestionId</comment>
            </column>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.xminds.bestfriend.frontend.model.QuestionConsumption" />
    </set>
</class>
```

getting exception

```
WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
```

ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - Duplicate entry '1019306207_10200395396740374' for key 'PRIMARY'
ERROR AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.xminds.bestfriend.frontend.model.Question]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2436)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2856)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
    at com.xminds.bestfriend.consumers.Base.onMessage(Base.java:89)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:339)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:535)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:495)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1019306207_10200395396740374' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2416)
    ... 25 more
ERROR QuestionGeneration - Unable to process task ID : 208
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [com.xminds.bestfriend.frontend.model.Question]; SQL [insert into question (answer_uid, question_type_id, data1, data2, fb_created_date, perma_link, fb_updated_date, content_activity, nb_consumptions, created_date, updated_date, cover_url, category, width, height, cover_offset_x, cover_offset_y, latitude, longitude, is_active, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.xminds.bestfriend.frontend.model.Question]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:637)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
    at com.xminds.bestfriend.consumers.Base.onMessage(Base.java:89)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:339)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:535)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:495)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.xminds.bestfriend.frontend.model.Question]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2436)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2856)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1019306207_10200395396740374' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2416)
    ... 25 more

```
@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(Object instance)
{

    //log.debug("attaching dirty  instance");
    try
    {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(instance);
        //log.debug("attach successful");
    }
    catch (RuntimeException re)
    {
       // log.error("attach failed", re);
        throw re;
    }

}
```

Comment: Something wrong with your transactions then?

Comment: What versino of hibernate you're using? Show us your HibernateUtil or sessionhandler.

Comment: I don't see how saveOrUpdate() could help avoiding duplicates If the entity has an ID, it will be updated. If it doesn't have one it will be inserted. Without seeing the code, it's hard to tell what can be wrong.

Comment: Here, In my case, id(primary key) is not auto-incremented and every time I will set its value.. But sometimes I am getting exception 
WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - Duplicate entry '1291270524_10200228165008751' for key 'PRIMARY'
ERROR AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session

Comment: Hibernate version : 3.6.0.Final

Comment: So, you don't get duplicate entries. You get an exception because two parallel transactions tried to persist the same PK. Isn't that expected? Catch the exception, rollback your transaction, and retry it.

Comment: @JBNizet Let me try :)

Answer (score 0):

You said,"My application contains several threads running concurrently and all threads either inserts or updates several rows in my tables". And you are setting your ID manually.
I want to know, the ID which you are setting to your threads, how are you getting them ?

Comment: It is fixed ;) I tried as in below comment
 "So, you don't get duplicate entries. You get an exception because two parallel transactions tried to persist the same PK. Isn't that expected? Catch the exception, rollback your transaction, and retry it. – JB Nizet"

Comment: Throwing an Exception is expected, but you have to catch the appropriate exception then rollback the transaction.
Its good that it has been fixed.
Can you explain a bit how you fixed it ?

Comment: I have put my code in loop with "attemptcount as 3", if fails committing then it will try again, most of the time it goes success within 2 attempts. I hope u understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You said 'In my case, id(primary key) is not auto-incremented and every time I will set its value'. This is the problem. You should make sure the generated id by yourself should be unique, during multiple threads.

There is 2 ways, 1, using auto-incremented column.
2, using something like UUID to create id. If you just using one jvm, with multiple threads, there is many ways or libs to help you to do that.